# pow function gives unwanted result c

Tags: c

for an assignment i've been asked to write a program that calculates Geometric and arithmetic mean in regular c.
i wrote this function:

```
double Geometric_mean(int number[], int n) //number[5]={1,2,3,4,5},n=5
{
    int i;
    double mean = 1;
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        mean =mean*number[i];
    }
    mean = pow(mean,1/n); //mean=120
    return(mean); //mean=1
}
```

i get the desired result before the pow turns it to 1 instead the of the desired 2.605

Comment: "calculates Geometric and arithmetic mean in *regular c*". So why did you tag C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `1`and `n` are `int`s, `1/n` is an euclidean division whose result is `0` for any `n > 1`.

You should use a `double` division:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>

double gmean(const int data[], std::size_t datasize)
{
    double product = 1.0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < datasize ; i++)
    {
        product *= data[i];
    }
    return std::pow(product, 1.0/datasize);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/155ffac2b1ca73ae).

Note that I've answer in C++. C and C++ are two separate languages and you should choose which one to use beforehand.

Comment: I would prefer `1.0/n` instead of the static cast

Answer (score 2):

You using integral division pow(mean,1/n); the result of 1/n  is zero if n > 1. You should convert it to float or double :

```
pow(mean,1.0/n);
```

or

```
pow(mean,1/(double)n);
```

Comment: and why not `1.0/(double)n` ??? Why forcing with a cast the compiler to do another cast?  Of course, all are correct, but why to insist in using integers if the whole operation is floating point?  Newbies get a better instruction if they learn from the beginning to distinguish floating point literals (numbers **with** an explicit decimal point) from integer literals (they don't have a dot)